# Is there a Mini DV tape to USB adapter?

Tags: usb, import, adapter, tape, mini-dv

I have Mini DV tapes, Hi8 or something lol. I have a camera that will not play them back, too choppy and cleaning has no effect. Is there a player, or adapter that can just read them into a computer? Thanks.

Comment: "Or something"? Try looking at the tape and reading what it shows.

Comment: Or, lookup the camera model to check what it takes.

Comment: Surely there's no adapter, like, I've never seen an adapter that can read tapes, like. Unless you count those, like, VHS-to-NTSC adapters or something, lulz, rotfl, omfg...

Answer (score 2):

Sony made both Mini DV and Hi8 VCRs with a Firewire interface (they call it "i.Link DV") that you can connect to your computer so that apps such as Adobe Premiere can control it and transfer the contents to the computer. You can find them used on eBay and Amazon partners and such.

Comment: Sorry guys I know that. I have tried running from FireWire to final cut pro but the camera itself won't play properly I need another delivery device. Does that make sense?

Comment: That would be why I said "VCR"...

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to play Long Play DV tapes on a machine that doesn't support LP? Or indeed [DVCam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DV#DVCAM) tapes on a DV machine? There are a few DV formats that use the same physical tapes, but the way the information is laid down on the tape is incompatible. If that's the case, you'll need another machine to play them back. Find out what the camera they were shot on was, and see if it's compatible with your playback device.